# R: Summarize groups of rows in one data.frame with groups based on whether a date column's value falls in a time range in another data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, rows, rowsum

I am trying to find the rows sums for each column in data frame *df_count* (cars, buses,trucks) between the time frames given in each row in the data frame *start_end*

So for example, row 1 of *start_end* ranges from 2021-06-12 00:15:00 to 2021-06-12 00:55:00.

I want to find the row sum of cars (for example) between these timestamps in column 1 of *df_count* (rows 5 to 12)

```
 df_count <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1623456000, 1623456300, 1623456600, 
    1623456900, 1623457200, 1623457500, 1623457800, 1623458100, 1623458400, 
    1623458700, 1623459000, 1623459300, 1623459600, 1623459900, 1623460200, 
    1623460500, 1623460800, 1623461100, 1623461400, 1623461700, 1623462000, 
    1623462300, 1623462600, 1623462900, 1623463200, 1623463500, 1623463800, 
    1623464100, 1623464400, 1623464700), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), cars = c(45, 45, 45, 52, 52, 52, 46, 46, 46, 34, 
    34, 34, 29, 29, 29, 36, 36, 36, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 14, 14, 
    14, 3, 3, 3), buses = c(4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
    5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), trucks = c(3, 
    3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 
    2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))
    
    start_end <- structure(list(start_co2_plume = c("2021-06-12 00:15:00", "2021-06-12 00:55:00", 
    "2021-06-12 01:15:00", "2021-06-12 01:30:00", "2021-06-12 02:00:00", 
    "2021-06-12 02:25:00", "2021-06-12 03:00:00", "2021-06-12 03:20:00", 
    "2021-06-12 03:45:00", "2021-06-12 03:55:00", "2021-06-12 04:20:00", 
    "2021-06-12 04:35:00", "2021-06-12 04:50:00", "2021-06-12 05:10:00", 
    "2021-06-12 05:40:00", "2021-06-12 05:50:00", "2021-06-12 06:00:00", 
    "2021-06-12 06:10:00", "2021-06-12 06:25:00", "2021-06-12 06:35:00", 
    "2021-06-12 06:45:00", "2021-06-12 06:55:00", "2021-06-12 08:10:00", 
    "2021-06-12 08:30:00", "2021-06-12 08:55:00", "2021-06-12 09:45:00", 
    "2021-06-12 10:05:00", "2021-06-12 10:35:00", "2021-06-12 11:05:00", 
    "2021-06-12 11:25:00"), end_co2_plume = c("2021-06-12 00:55:00", 
    "2021-06-12 01:15:00", "2021-06-12 01:30:00", "2021-06-12 02:00:00", 
    "2021-06-12 02:25:00", "2021-06-12 03:00:00", "2021-06-12 03:20:00", 
    "2021-06-12 03:35:00", "2021-06-12 03:55:00", "2021-06-12 04:10:00", 
    "2021-06-12 04:35:00", "2021-06-12 04:50:00", "2021-06-12 05:10:00", 
    "2021-06-12 05:30:00", "2021-06-12 05:50:00", "2021-06-12 06:00:00", 
    "2021-06-12 06:10:00", "2021-06-12 06:25:00", "2021-06-12 06:35:00", 
    "2021-06-12 06:45:00", "2021-06-12 06:55:00", "2021-06-12 07:10:00", 
    "2021-06-12 08:30:00", "2021-06-12 08:55:00", "2021-06-12 09:10:00", 
    "2021-06-12 10:05:00", "2021-06-12 10:25:00", "2021-06-12 10:50:00", 
    "2021-06-12 11:25:00", "2021-06-12 11:45:00")), row.names = c(NA, 
    30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Tried to clean up the question language. I don't think the OP actually means row sums here - in fact, I think they mean column sums (which is what you call summing the values in a single column but across multiple rows). This is because they note that they want, within the time window, the total number of cars across all rows. Accordingly my solution addresses that.

Answer (score 0):

The below produces the desired output. It is necessary to assume  the time zones for the dates, so I assumed they came from the same time zone.

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

# Convert dates in start_end from character vectors to date classes
# Assumes the times are in the same time zone
start_end <- start_end %>% mutate(start_date = as.POSIXct(start_co2_plume, tz = "UTC"),
                                  end_date = as.POSIXct(end_co2_plume, tz = "UTC"))

# For each row in start_end, subset df_count to the rows whose dates fall in
# the the interval defined by the start_date and end_date values for that row.
# For each automobile column, sum the values and add an index to tell us which
# interval it came from. 
results <-
  pmap(list(start_end$start_date, start_end$end_date, 1:nrow(start_end)),
       function(start, end, ind) {
         df_count %>%
           filter((date >= start) & (date < end)) %>%
           select(-date) %>%
           summarise(across(everything(), sum)) %>%
           mutate(interval_id = ind,
                  start = start,
                  end = end)
       })

# Combine into a single data.frame
results %>% bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 30 x 6
#>     cars buses trucks interval_id start               end                
#>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>       <int> <dttm>              <dttm>             
#>  1   362    44     26           1 2021-06-12 00:15:00 2021-06-12 00:55:00
#>  2   121    19     13           2 2021-06-12 00:55:00 2021-06-12 01:15:00
#>  3   108    12      9           3 2021-06-12 01:15:00 2021-06-12 01:30:00
#>  4   105    12     15           4 2021-06-12 01:30:00 2021-06-12 02:00:00
#>  5    48     5      5           5 2021-06-12 02:00:00 2021-06-12 02:25:00
#>  6     3     1      1           6 2021-06-12 02:25:00 2021-06-12 03:00:00
#>  7     0     0      0           7 2021-06-12 03:00:00 2021-06-12 03:20:00
#>  8     0     0      0           8 2021-06-12 03:20:00 2021-06-12 03:35:00
#>  9     0     0      0           9 2021-06-12 03:45:00 2021-06-12 03:55:00
#> 10     0     0      0          10 2021-06-12 03:55:00 2021-06-12 04:10:00
#> # ... with 20 more rows
```